# Cannot get the request body in the Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a `FormData` object and append with two fields `audio` and `email`. When i use axios to send a request, i cannot receive request body in the backend.

```js
const email = 'my@gmail';
const url = 'http://';

const sendData = () =>{

 let fd = new FormData();

 const audio = new Blob(audioData, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });

 fd.append('audio' , audio);
 fd.append('email', email);

 const resp =  await axios.post(url, fd);
```

Backend side.

```js
// First middleware 

const { User } = require("../models/userSchema");

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.body); // {}

    next();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`~ header.

```js
const sendData = () =>{
 let fd = new FormData();
 const audio = new Blob(audioData, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
 fd.append('audio' , audio);
 fd.append('email', email);

 const resp =  await axios.post(url, fd, {
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
 });
 console.log(resp);
```

Comment: I have put the header , but still i get an empty object {} at the API side

Comment: It looks as if you're not parsing the `multipart/form-data` content. Since `body-parser` doesn't parse multipart data. Please consider using the `multer` npm module for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in addition to the above comments, `multipart/form-data` was required in this case because its used in uploading form data to server in multiple parts because of large file size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).